# Discrete Math Binomial Theorem Formula

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, logic

### Binomial Theorem Formula:

- Sigma Notation:
  $\sum_{i=0}^{n} $ $n\choose i $$ x^i $ $y^{(n-i)}$

Note: $(n-i)$  is the exponent of $y$.

### Logical Question:

- Can the place of exponents for $x$ and $y$ be switched ?

Ex. 
$\sum_{i=0}^{n} $ $n\choose i $$ x^{(n-i)} $ $y^i$

Note: Now $(n-i)$ is the exponent of $x$.

Comment: you should use braces to obtain $x^{n-i}$ instead of $x^(n-i)$

Comment: The key for your question is the symmetry of binomial coefficients : $\binom nk=\binom n{n-k}$

Comment: Ok. Yes, that was the key to this problem. Thank you!  I believe you should post the second comment as the answer to this question and I will accept it and upvote it for you.

Comment: `x^{(n-i)}` instead of `x^(n-i)`

Comment: Yes indeed. Fixed it now.  2 other people agreed that it is possible to switch the exponents of i and n - i for x and y. Try n choose k and then n choose n - k. Substitute the exponents and you'll see the exponents of x and y can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Note that $$(x+y)^n = (y+x)^n$$

The general term of the first expression is $\binom {n}{r}x^ry^{n-r } $ and in the second case is $\binom{n}{r}y^rx^{n-r} = \binom {n}{n-r}x^ry^{n-r} $. Thus, both expressions are equivalent. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, so we can switch the place of exponents since for addition and multiplication there is the option of replacement. Thus, it indicates exponents can be switched as well ?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The key for your question is the symmetry of binomial coefficients ... for all integers $n,k$ such that $0\le k\le n$ we have :

$$\binom nk=\binom n{n-k}$$

This can be understood  with a combinatorial argument : given a set $E$ such that $\mathrm{card}(E)=n$ and an integer $k$ such that $0\le k\le n$, there exists a bijection from the set $\mathcal{P}_k(E)$ of subsets of $A\subset E$ such that $\mathrm{card}(A)=k$ to the set $\mathcal{P}_{n-k}(E)$ : map $A$ to $E-A$.

Comment: 0 ≤ k ≤ n is another important key point.